# Portable codes to open URLs

Tags: python

On MacOS, I will open a url with code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('open http://www.google.com', shell=True)
```

On windows, it can be done by:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('start www.google.com', shell=True)
```

How to enable codes applied to both MacOS and windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Python's `webbrowser` module instead of `subprocess`:

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open("www.google.com")
```

This should work on most operating systems, since it doesn't rely on any OS-specific commands.